# FadeOut after mouseleave then click jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, mouseleave, fadeout

I have some `DIV` that fades in by clicking another DIV trigger element. I cannot came up with a script that will:

- On mouse leave then click outside -**fade out** the `DIV`

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You really need to show your work dude to give us a better idea of how we can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, this is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var button = $("#div1");
  var container = $("#div2");    

  button.on('click', function(){

       container.fadeIn();

  });      

  $(document).mouseup(function (e){

        // check if click target is element or one of its children
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.find(e.target).length == 0){

            container.fadeOut();

        }
  });

});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neQuK/